# Css 3 - To configure border color in html table

Tags: css

I want to do a table as the next image:

[image]

I have the table html code , but I need to change the border color as in the image.

I did it a long time ago, but I would like to know the best way by do it now.

Always are the same rows and columns, but is mandatory one requisite, must be done with only css, maybe using:

```
tr:nth-child(3)
```

This is the table html code:

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="6" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
        <tr><th>Field1</th><th>Field2</th><th>Field3</th><th>Field4</th><th>Field5</th><th>Field6</th><th>Field7</th><th>Field8</th><th>Field9</th></tr>
    </thead>            
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td><td>7</td><td>8</td><td>9</td></tr> 
        <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td><td>7</td><td>8</td><td>9</td></tr>
        <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td><td>7</td><td>8</td><td>9</td></tr>
        <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td><td>7</td><td>8</td><td>9</td></tr> 
        <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td><td>7</td><td>8</td><td>9</td></tr>
        <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td><td>7</td><td>8</td><td>9</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

How I could do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
tr > td:nth-child(7), tr > th:nth-child(7){
  border-right: orange 2px solid;
}
tr > td:nth-child(8), tr > th:nth-child(8){
  border-left: orange 2px solid;
}

tr:nth-child(3) > td{
  border-bottom: orange 2px solid;
}
tr:nth-child(4) > td{
  border-top: orange 2px solid;
}
```

```html
<table border="1" cellpadding="6" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
        <tr><th>Field1</th><th>Field2</th><th>Field3</th><th>Field4</th><th>Field5</th><th>Field6</th><th>Field7</th><th>Field8</th><th>Field9</th></tr>
    </thead>            
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td><td>7</td><td>8</td><td>9</td></tr> 
        <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td><td>7</td><td>8</td><td>9</td></tr>
        <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td><td>7</td><td>8</td><td>9</td></tr>
        <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td><td>7</td><td>8</td><td>9</td></tr> 
        <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td><td>7</td><td>8</td><td>9</td></tr>
        <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td><td>7</td><td>8</td><td>9</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: @Eladerezador It's my pleasure :)